# Python tweepy find user of search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
import time
import tweepy

from auth import consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret

string_to_search = 'new car ideas'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

past_status_ids = set()

while True:
    tweets = api.search(q=string_to_search)
tweet_id_list = set([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
new_tweet_ids = tweet_id_list - past_status_ids
past_status_ids = tweet_id_list | past_status_ids



for tweet_id in new_tweet_ids:
    print "Retweeting " + str(tweet_id)
    api.retweet(tweet_id)
    #username = tweets.user.screen_name
    #api.create_friendship(username)
    #print "Followed " + str(username)
    limits = api.rate_limit_status()
    remain_search_limits = limits['resources']['search']['/search/tweets']['remaining']
    print("Limit left is " + str(remain_search_limits))
    print("")
    time.sleep(150)
```

In a nutshell I am trying to find a string, then take that string retweet on my feed and follow that person.

My issue is how am I to find the Twitter ID to follow them via the search string?

I have been searching all around and can't find too many examples in Python tweepy for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the User ID of the user who tweeted the tweet with status id tweet_id.
Use this

```
tweet = api.get_status(tweet_id)
user_id = tweet.user.id
# Now follow that user
api.create_friendship(user_id)
```